# Picture Size html and css

Tags: html, css

I have a drop down menu of products and I want a picture of the product next to each option in the drop down. I am using this line to do this

```
<img src="http://www.products.com/products/product1.png" 
alt="Product1" height="20" width="22" class="itemImg" 
style="float:right;position:absolute; top: 6px; right: 20px;">
```

However when copying this line to use in multiple products not all pictures will look the same size even though I am giving the height and the width. Is it possible to make all pictures the same size immediately without having to modify the height and width for each picture?

Comment: You could use [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to reproduce your code. I don't think someone here will try to replicate your problem just from an `img` tag.

Comment: give the complete scripts, HTML and CSS with a block.

Comment: Please provide a working JSFiddle of what you have tried..

Comment: This is one of the options of the drop down menu` <li>
   <a href="http://www.products.com/products/item1.php">item</a>
   <img src="http:/www.products.com/products/product1.png" alt="prod1" height="20" width="22" class="itemImg" style="float:right;position:absolute; top: 6px; right: 20px;">
  </li>` CSS is inckuded with the html using the style tag

Comment: @JustinSpiteri Use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) as Mihai mentioned. To solve it faster...

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is very unclear you should provide some more code but Yes! you can apply `css` for making pictures to same size. And remove `position: absolute` because all will overlap to each other.
 i created a snippet check this hope it will works.

```css
img.itemImg{width:150px; height:150px; background-color:green; position:relative !important;}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.products.com/products/product1.png" 
alt="Product1" height="20" width="22" class="itemImg" 
style="float:right;position:absolute; top: 6px; right: 20px;">

<img src="http://www.products.com/products/product1.png" 
alt="Product1" height="20" width="22" class="itemImg" 
style="float:right;position:absolute; top: 6px; right: 20px;">

<img src="http://www.products.com/products/product1.png" 
alt="Product1" height="20" width="22" class="itemImg" 
style="float:right;position:absolute; top: 6px; right: 20px;">

<img src="http://www.products.com/products/product1.png" 
alt="Product1" height="20" width="22" class="itemImg" 
style="float:right;position:absolute; top: 6px; right: 20px;">


<img src="http://www.products.com/products/product1.png" 
alt="Product1" height="20" width="22" class="itemImg" 
style="float:right;position:absolute; top: 6px; right: 20px;">

<img src="http://www.products.com/products/product1.png" 
alt="Product1" height="20" width="22" class="itemImg" 
style="float:right;position:absolute; top: 6px; right: 20px;">

<img src="http://www.products.com/products/product1.png" 
alt="Product1" height="20" width="22" class="itemImg" 
style="float:right;position:absolute; top: 6px; right: 20px;">

<img src="http://www.products.com/products/product1.png" 
alt="Product1" height="20" width="22" class="itemImg" 
style="float:right;position:absolute; top: 6px; right: 20px;">

<img src="http://www.products.com/products/product1.png" 
alt="Product1" height="20" width="22" class="itemImg" 
style="float:right;position:absolute; top: 6px; right: 20px;">

<img src="http://www.products.com/products/product1.png" 
alt="Product1" height="20" width="22" class="itemImg" 
style="float:right;position:absolute; top: 6px; right: 20px;">
```